# Python 3: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, matplotlib, compiler-errors

I'm currently learning matplot and I saw this code on the official tutorial, but I got the error *unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'*. How could I fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

names = ["a", "b", "c"]
values = [1, 10, 100]

plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))

plt.subplot(131)
plt.bar(names, values)
plt.subplot(132)
plt.scatter(names, values)
plt.subplot(133)
plt.plot(names, values)
plt.suptitle('Categorical Plotting')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your misbehaviour. For me the code works fine.

Comment: Can you add the full traceback?

Comment: code works for me without problem. Maybe you have error in different code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: as pointed below, your code is also correct

plt.bar expects the first argument to be the x-coordinates of your bars, not labels. You can put the labels by doing:

```
plt.bar([1,2,3], values, tick_label=names)
```

Answer (score 3):

the provided code works well, I do not see any error (I'm using python 3.7):
 [image]